# Issue connecting redis cluster using redisson

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster, redisson

I am trying to connect redis cluster using redisson 2.3.0 and redis 5.0.7.

Java code for connection:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useClusterServers()
.addNodeAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:8000");
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```

It is giving following error::

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.(InetSocketAddress.java:224)
at org.redisson.client.RedisClient.(RedisClient.java:93)
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.createClient(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:310)
at org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager.connect(ClusterConnectionManager.java:150)
at org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager.(ClusterConnectionManager.java:81)
at org.redisson.config.ConfigSupport.createConnectionManager(ConfigSupport.java:172)
at org.redisson.Redisson.(Redisson.java:103)
at org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:133)
```

Cluster config from CLUSTER_NODES in redisson CLusterConnectionManager::

```
[ClusterNodeInfo [nodeId=4317f285b359ddc3ac08bb85239924509146e475, address=//127.0.0.1:8003@18003, flags=[SLAVE], slaveOf=4118a348827e6107d7e35522a251fd39c5a8f82b, slotRanges=[]], 
ClusterNodeInfo [nodeId=2f7b93c80d3721b3fb26fe87bc28ed04a63fe0ec, address=//127.0.0.1:8005@18005, flags=[SLAVE], slaveOf=8b81c3e1acb4e1959a83267540058d1a6bffa12f, slotRanges=[]], 
ClusterNodeInfo [nodeId=4118a348827e6107d7e35522a251fd39c5a8f82b, address=//127.0.0.1:8001@18001, flags=[MASTER], slaveOf=null, slotRanges=[[5461-10922]]],
ClusterNodeInfo [nodeId=a0770863d893a5b8106a83e247cea2544f99ef36, address=//127.0.0.1:8004@18004, flags=[SLAVE], slaveOf=6b9da1bbe38b978a3017406e5c1e310f4706cfc8, slotRanges=[]], 
ClusterNodeInfo [nodeId=8b81c3e1acb4e1959a83267540058d1a6bffa12f, address=//127.0.0.1:8000@18000, flags=[MYSELF, MASTER], slaveOf=null, slotRanges=[[0-5460]]],
ClusterNodeInfo [nodeId=6b9da1bbe38b978a3017406e5c1e310f4706cfc8, address=//127.0.0.1:8002@18002, flags=[MASTER], slaveOf=null, slotRanges=[[10923-16383]]]]
```

Reason i found after debugging is :
**Not generating ClientPartition.getMasterAddress() properly.
Address is //127.0.0.1:8001@18001 as recorded by CLUSTER_NODES, but it reads it as host: 18001 and port=-1,  i.e reading the cluster bus port.**

Please suggest where i am doing wrong config.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest here is to move the redisson to latest version. Could you please check with latest one ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Anuj.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have already found a solution, but I'm providing an answer in case others are facing a similar issue.

The error you encountered seems to be related to how you are setting the node addresses. Starting from Redisson version 2.7.X, you need to use the redis:// protocol in the node addresses. However, for versions before 2.7.X, you should not use the redis:// protocol.

To fix the issue, please try the following:

**For Redisson versions 2.7.X and above:**

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useClusterServers()
.addNodeAddress("redis://localhost:6001", "redis://localhost:6001");
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```

**For Redisson versions before 2.7.X:**

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useClusterServers()
.addNodeAddress("localhost:6001", "localhost:6002");
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```

Make sure to replace the port numbers and hostnames with the appropriate values for your Redis cluster configuration.

I hope this helps!

Comment: What makes you think they've found a solution?